# Cannot "Baking the Wiggle" in Blender v2.92.0

Tags: animation, rigging, add-on, bones, baking

When I try to "Bake the Wiggle", it gives me this error

[image: blender error]

I searched for a fix and tried one but it still doesn't work. Changing type of a rig but I don't have any *RigType* options.

- *Blender* : `2.92.0`
- *Wiggle Bones* : `1.5-b16`

Note: This error appears on all bones

Disabling "Additive Bake" solved the problem for me.

Comment: If disabling "Additive Bake" solved the problem for you, you can add this as an answer to your own question and accept the answer. This way, future readers with the same problem can see that there is a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Disabling "Additive Bake" solved my problem!

I think there was a problem with the add-on, or the "compatibility" of the NLA. (?)

> *When you do an additive bake, it pushes your animation into an NLA strip and bakes the wiggle into the active action.* — [blenderartists.org](https://blenderartists.org/)

? = I don't know how blender's add-ons system is working, but reopening the editor or reload the same file can also solve the problem. (*maybe a corrupted code sequence in the add-on*)

Comment: Welcome to BSE! Could you add some details about this solution to explain why the *Additive Bake* option was the problem, and how disabling it solved the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I was also successful by baking the animation this way, turning off wiggle 2 (armature and world) after setting up. Then object, animation, bake animation and check: only selected bones, visual keying, overwrite current action and hit bake action.

You can always <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>, but it worked perfectly. When I was trying to bake the wiggle it was a bit too much wiggle, if you know what I mean.

Going to try disabling additive bake next, but thought I'd share the following that helped me (because I wasted a day trying to adjust the wiggle attributes as it looked fine and would render totally different).

https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/q2wlgq/wiggle_bones_baking_problem/